# RVM fails to install Rubies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, cygwin, rvm

Why is RVM failing to install ruby?

My development machine died and I am recreating my development environment on another machine Cygwin 32 bit, Win 7 64 bit and RVM.  I've installed RVM using the standard `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash` and by following this script [Installing RVM With Cygwin on Windows](http://blog.developwithpassion.com/2012/03/30/installing-rvm-with-cygwin-on-windows/) and installing RVM with Ruby `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`. RVM seems to install successfully each time but when I try to install a version of Ruby using RVM I get this message:

> Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time. No binary
>   rubies available for: cygwin/unknown/i386/ruby-2.0.0-p353. Continuing
>   with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information
>   on binary rubies. Checking requirements for cygwin. Requirements
>   support for cygwin is not implemented yet, report a bug here =>
>   https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues Requirements installation
>   failed with status: 1.

I do not remember in my previous, same config, setup having any issues with RVM. I had multiple versions of Ruby installed and was able to move between them with RVM.

I installed Ruby 1.9.3 successfully with the Cygwin setup program outside of RVM. Similar error with Cygwin 64 bit.

I have installed and uninstalled Cygwin several times, the same with RVM without success. After much searching and trial and error I've begun focusing on this `cygwin/unknown/i386/ruby-2.0.0-p353` Is it possibly a PATH environmental variable issue? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have two options:

1. disable `autolibs`: `rvm autolibs disable`
2. switch to [branch with cygwin development](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/pull/2360):

   ```
   rvm get branch /features/cygwin
   rvm requirements
   ```

Comment: Working on #2 right now. I had to play with PATH for the RVM scripts to find setup.exe (or setup-x86_64.exe)

Comment: please leave notes about any issues (and possible solutions) here => https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/pull/2360

Comment: @ToddiusZho  any luck doing that?   I am on a mac, and learning cygwin on windows 7, would love to know what to edit the $PATH with

Comment: I tried today with newer versions and everything seemed to work. rvm get stable; rvm install 2.1.1; rvm install 2.1.2